# Android Studio IDE Error Indication

Tags: android, android-studio

I am relatively new to StackOverflow and Android Studio so apologies for newbie question!

I recently switched over to Android Studio from Eclipse.

I am noticing that when one function in one of my source files has an error that ALL functions in that file on the project view pane on the top left are showing the red squiggly so it is a little more time consuming to actually get to the error. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: Would you show us a screenshot, and if possible a few examples of errors that are raised? Knowing the Studio version number would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shlublu points out, it is difficult to say without an example. Here is one possible situation. Take this class:

```
public class MyClass {

    private int myNumber;

    public MyClass( int number) {
        this.myNumber = number;
    }

    public int getAnswer() {
       return this.myNumber;
    }

    private void  someMethod() {
        int x = 0;
    } //  remove this } and all below is an error

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.myNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public  boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Removing the } at the end of the `someMethod()` causes all methods below that to have an error.